# Do i need create new certificates to update/upgrade a app in appstore?

Tags: app-store, certificate, upgrade, apple-push-notifications

I have a application in the appStore that use push notifications.

I've generated a new version of this app, and using the same certificates that I used the first time that I submitted the app in the market, I have submitted the update to appStore.

After approve the app, I've noticed the push notification doesn't work after updated the app in the devices.

Could be this wrong behavior done for using the same certificates than before???

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Updating an application using same certificates as before won't change the working status of push notification.

Maybe your problem is on server side and your push notification certificate is out of date and need to be regenerated. Push certificates have a validity of about one year.